# How to seperate each tweet into different bootstrap cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, tweets

I am trying to display the latest 'n' tweets on a website inside the bootstrap rows/col format. Currently, the code I have displays the latest 'n' tweets but they are all in verticle format.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
      href="https://twitter.com/twitter"
      data-tweet-limit="10">
Tweets by @twitter</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

So basically i am looking for a way to style these tweets by putting each tweet inside a column.
So something like this

```
<div class="row>
<?php 
foreach($tweets as $tweet){
  echo '<div class="col">
         <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
           //The embedded code to display the tweet
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>';
}
```

In a nutsell : I am trying to display latest 'n' tweets in an embedded view in bootstrap rows and column format.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php foreach($tweets as $tweet): ?>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
         <?= $tweet; ?> <!-- Assuming $tweet is a string -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Above, I am using the [alternative syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Also, `<?=` is syntax sugar for `<?php echo`

Comment: php wont have the tweets the OP is using a js widget

Comment: In that case, this should be a JavaScript question. PHP code / label should be removed.